# Set secure_file_priv=NULL in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, security, mariadb, configuration

In order to secure my server, I'd like to set:

```
secure_file_priv = NULL
```

As per MySQL's docs - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

> If set to NULL, the server disables import and export operations. This value is permitted as of MySQL 5.7.6.

However, that value doesn't seem to be in MariaDB's docs - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#secure_file_priv

If I try `NULL` in MariaDB 10, I get this error:

> [Warning] Failed to normalize the argument for --secure-file-priv.

What do you recommend to prevent import/export operations?

If I set to a given folder, will things like `OUTFILE ../../../etc/my.cnf` work? (i.e., relative paths, going level ups)

Comment: `local_infile = ON` has some security issues.  Change to OFF.

Comment: set it to a non-existent folder to prevent/disable this operation..hope it helps